# @Grab defined in shared-library is not working while referencing library in another java pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We have created a pipeline shared library using Groovy and referenced that in one of java project. Build is getting success for shared library while running individual build, but when we reference the shared library and run the jenkins pipeline build of java project, it is getting failed with the below error.

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Pipeline%20Test/jobs/pipeline-test/branches/develop/builds/10/libs/c3-shared-library/src/com/test/c3/http/JenkinsHttpClient.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class jodd.http.HttpRequest
 @ line 6, column 1.
   @Grab("org.jodd:jodd-http:5.1.0")
```

**c3-shared-library** - JenkinsHttpClient.groovy:

```
#! /usr/bin/groovy
package com.test.c3.http

import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
@Grab("org.jodd:jodd-http:5.1.0")
import jodd.http.HttpRequest
import jodd.http.HttpResponse


class JenkinsHttpClient implements Serializable {

    private String userAgent


    JenkinsHttpClient(String userAgent = "Jenkins"){
        this.userAgent = userAgent
    }
```

Herewith attached jenkins configuration. Please check and provide your valuable inputs.

[image: Jenkins Configuration]

**Shared Library Pipeline build.grade:**

```
group "com.test.c3"
version "1.0.0-develop-SNAPSHOT"

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compileGroovy {
    groovyOptions.configurationScript = file("gradle/config.groovy")
}

sourceSets {
    groovy {
        main.groovy.srcDirs += 'src/'
        main.groovy.srcDirs += 'vars/'
        test.groovy.srcDirs += 'tests/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.5.0"
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.9'
    compile 'org.jodd:jodd-http:5.1.0'
    compile 'com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.31'

    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
}
```